# Upper bound for complete binary tree structure based quadratic quantity.

Tags: computational-complexity, trees, upper-lower-bounds

A complete binary tree is defined as a tree where each node has either 2 or 0 children.

Suppose given a complete binary tree with $n$ leaves, there are $n-1$ internal nodes.

For any node $i$ , denote the depth of left subtree $l_i$, and the depth of right subtree $r_i$.

For each node $i$ of this tree, i'm interested in this quantity: $q(i) := max(l_i, r_i)*min(l_i, r_i) - min(l_i, r_i)^2 $

Now my question is what's the upper bound of sum over all internal nodes: $Q = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} q(i)$ ?

The lower bound is simple to have, when the tree is balanced then $q(i) = 0$, thus $Q=0$.

---

Some attempt: denotes the maximum depth of the tree as $d$, then the maximum level 1 quantity is reached when one sub-tree has depth $d-1$, and the other sub-tree has depth $d/2$. Then we can derive the recusive quantity $Q(d) = Q(d-1) + Q(d/2) + (d-1 - d/2)*d/2$, and the $Q(1)$ is simply 1.

Comment: $\max(l_i,r_i)\cdot \min(l_i,r_i) = l_i\cdot r_i$

Comment: FYI - while you are correct that my argument was garbage - an embarassing mistake - I still think the linear tree where only one branch ever has more than a single leaf is still maximal. It is clear that if the overall tree is large enough, the contribution of any subtree of a given size would be maximized by making it linear.

Comment: yeah, "single leaf  per level is the maximum tree" is what i felt to be true. but i don't have a good proof :(. @PaulSinclair